# Find the values of Matrix that makes it a rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, matrix-equations

I have  the next problem:

*Find the values for wich the matrix is a rotation ($M\cdot M^{t}=Id$, $\det M= 1$):*
\begin{equation*}
M= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a & * & 0 \\
  b & * & * \\
  c & * & * \end{array} \right) \; \; \;  i f \; \; \; bc\neq 0
\end{equation*}
where $a, b, c$ are known constants.

I tried to apply the two conditions but I got stuck.
This is my proccedure:

\begin{align*}
M\cdot M^{t}&= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a & x_1 & 0 \\
  b & x_2 & x_4 \\
  c & x_3 & x_5 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\
  x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
  0 & x_4 & x_5 \end{array} \right) \newline &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a^2 +x_1^2 & ab + x_1 x_2 & ac +x_1 x_3 \\
  ab+ x_1 x_2&b^2+x_2^2+x_4^2& bc+x_2x_3+x_4 x_5 \\
  ac+x_1 x_3 & bc+x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5 & c^2 + x_3^2 +x_5^2 \end{array} \right) \newline &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)
\end{align*}

That give me 6 equations and with the condition $\det M =1$ I get $a(x_2 x_5 - x_4 x_3)-x_1(bx_5 -cx_4)=1$  and I don't know what to do now. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M^{T}M = \mathcal{I}$ then the columns vectors of $M$ are orthonormal to each other (orthonormal because the determinant is unity: $\textrm{det}(M^{T}M) = \textrm{det}(M)^2=\textrm{det}(\mathcal{I})=1$):
$$m_i^{T}m_k=\delta_{ik}$$
being $m_i$ the $i$-th column of $M$.

From this you have (supposing $|(a,b,c)|=1$):
$$(0, m_{23}, m_{33})^{T}(a, b, c)=0$$
giving $m_{23}=c/\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ and $m_{33}=-b/\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ (for example)

The last vector must be perpendicular to the other two and be part of a right handed basis to preserve orientation ($\textrm{det}M=1$), therefore:
$m_2=m_3\times m_1/|m_3\times m_1|$

Comment: Thank you so much!! Corrected!

Comment: Might be worth adding something about the order of the cross product to your answer.